# Filtering and Searching Data Using Department of Labor Quarry API (v2)

Tags: api, labor

I am attempting to query the OSHA Inspection data from the DOL Quarry API as shown at http://developer.dol.gov/health-and-safety/dol-osha-enforcement/#osha_inspection. I have found API documentation at http://developer.dol.gov/accessing-the-apis-using-http-requests/ for data.dol.gov that indicates you can search by dates, however I would like to search by other fields like site_state or naics_code. I tried simply appending something like site_state/ct to my request and it did not filter or search. Is there anyway to do this or documentation I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [github.com/USDepartmentofLabor/DOLAPI/issues/12](http://github.com/USDepartmentofLabor/DOLAPI/issues/12) where we're tracking this issue. We don't yet support WHERE clauses in the request, but we're considering it and tracking that feature request in GitHub.